# why do we need typeof as a interface to get the static properties of a class in typescript

Tags: typescript, function, constructor, interface

I am learning the typescript official handbook explaining constructor functions and came across the following code.

```
class Greeter {
    static standardGreeting = "Hello, there";
    greeting: string;
    greet() {
        if (this.greeting) {
            return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
        }
        else {
            return Greeter.standardGreeting;
        }
    }
}

let greeter1: Greeter;
greeter1 = new Greeter();
console.log(greeter1.greet());

let greeterMaker: typeof Greeter = Greeter;
greeterMaker.standardGreeting = "Hey there!";

let greeter2: Greeter = new greeterMaker();
console.log(greeter2.greet());
```

It goes on to explain that when writing

> let greeterMaker: typeof Greeter = Greeter;

we are able to access the actual class with the static properties by using `typeof Greeter`, hence able to write `greeterMaker.standardGreeting = "Hey there!";`

My question is, when i tested this, i realised the same thing will work without writing `typeof Greeter` just with  `let greeterMaker = Greeter;` one is able to write `greeterMaker.standardGreeting = "Hey there!";`

Please can you tell me where i have gone wrong and when i need to write the typeof keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you don't need to use the `typeof Greeter` explicitly, the compiler will infer this type for you based on assignment. However `typeof Greeter` will still be the type `greeterMaker` even if you don't specify the annotation explicitly. I think the point the docs are making is that if you need the type of the static part that type is `typeof Greeter` while `Greeter` is the type of the instance.

An example where this might be useful is in a factory function:

```
class Greeter {
  sayHi() { console.log("Hi") }
}

class AlertGreeter extends Greeter {
  sayHi() { alert("Hi") }
}

function doGreeting(cls: typeof Greeter) {
  new cls().sayHi();
}

doGreeting(Greeter);
doGreeting(AlertGreeter);
```

Comment: Thanks. One quick question. Is the class AlertGreeter typeof Greeter only because it has the same function name. If its method would be called something else, would it still be typeof Greeter

Comment: @JoeStarbright `AlertGreeter` extends `Greeter`, it is compatible with `Greeter` because of this and because they both have an empty constructor

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're right, writing `:typeof Greeter` is not necessary in this case, as when you assign the value `Greater` for `greeterMaker`, it also assigns the type for `greeterMarker`. So I think `:typeof Greeter` is just an explanation about how Typescript work